# send data from iphone to azure

Tags: web-services, security, rest, azure

If I want to send some data from a mobile device to windows azure, is there any service that can help me?

Or do I need to create some REST services and call tham from the mobile? If I do this how should I assure that the sender of the data is the mobile and not some hacker? How should you secure that communication between the mobile ad the azure platform?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you create REST or OData services in Windows Azure. As for securing, it might be a bit of a hard work. But you can start looking at [Securing REST Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446531.aspx). The [Windows Azure Access Control Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee732536.aspx) could help you with the tokens. There are various samples [here](http://acs.codeplex.com/). Maybe [the sample for Windows Phone 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg192968) could be in some kind of help here also. Another article on [using ACS with iOS cabe found here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2011/07/25/using-the-windows-azure-access-control-service-in-ios-applications.aspx). And also some quick overview of the [Windows Azure SDK for iOS](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/07/windows-azure-toolkit-for-ios-now-supports-the-access-control-service/) that supports ACS.

Basic flow: your application will get a security token from ACS, then send this token to either a REST or OData service. Your service will validate the token and take approriate actions according the result.